# DNS NXDOMAIN error command certbot

Tags: ssl, nginx, dns, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to install a ssl certicate lets encrypt in my domain and my sub domaine.
I was sucessful installing the ssl certificate on my domain but i did't successful on my sub domain 
I use the next command

```
certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/sub-domain/maxime-mazet.fr/owncloud/ -d cloud.maxime-mazet.fr
```

/var/www/sub-domain/maxime-mazet.fr/owncloud has the folder of my code.
cloud.maxime-mazet.fr is my sub domain.

my domain maxime-mazet.fr is host at ovh.
for cloud.maxime-mazet.fr I have created the enter A with the IP of server.

with my domain (maxime-mazet.fr) no error but with my sub domain (cloud.maxime-mazet.fr) the error is

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for cloud.maxime-mazet.fr
Using the webroot path /var/www/sub-domain/maxime-mazet.fr/owncloud for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. cloud.maxime-mazet.fr (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for cloud.maxime-mazet.fr

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: cloud.maxime-mazet.fr
   Type:   connection
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for
   cloud.maxime-mazet.fr

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

The next pictures is my panel for the A of my domain and my sub domain

[image: I can't post a image I don't have 10 reputation but 8]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ns13.ovh.net` and `dns13.ovh.net` do not appear to be authoritative for your domain name as they do not properly reply to queries on it. You will first need to solve that problem. Ask OVH if they are indeed the correct hosts to use for your domain. Since you seem to just have changed recently something on your domain name, you may just need to wait a little for things to settle.

Have a look at `https://www.zonemaster.net/` to conduct tests on your zone. Until they are all ok do not play with Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the screen but the ns13 and dns13 is good i have a new screen with all enter ;)
[image]